# how to render multiple objects in one drawing loop

Tags: opengl

I am new to opengl with shaders and ran into trouble when trying to render more than one object in my drawing loop.

All the objects are organised in VAOs, they were copied to the CPU memory in 
modelspace. 
This means i have to change and recalculate the main matrices between drawing calls if position, rotation or scaling of one object has changed.

As long as i render only 1 object, everything works fine.
My understanding is that i pass the adress of my model or mvp matrix to the shaders.
If i change - external - the content of it between the drawing of different objects,
they will be drawn using the different contents of this variable.
I don't want to recompute the matices inside the shaders as their values remain
the same for the whole mesh of the current object.

This does not work - the matix is applied one time and all objects are drawn 
with its values.

How is that done in a game engine that has to render multiple objects in 
ONE drawing loop.

thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a typical rendering cycle, each object has it's own transform, which must be calculated independently of everything else. You don't need to recalculate your view or perspective transform though.

So, your typical rendering cycle would go like this:

For each object:

1. Check if object is visible (use a flag or something)
2. If (1), recompute it's transform matrix, and enable the shader
3. Send matrix data to the shader
4. Bind any lights, and related lighting data
5. Bind the VAO and any textures(materials) associated with the mesh.
6. Call `glDrawArrays` on the VAO handle, using the vertex/index count as an argument.
7. Unbind everything, disable the shader and continue to next object.

As you can see from this cycle, each transform is unique to each object. That is not the case for anything else. A VAO and materials can be reused, as can the view and projection matrices.

So, you don't compute matrices on the gpu, you do it on the cpu, then send the result to the shader as a uniform.